# Show one2many field in a tree view of different model [Odoo]

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I want to display all the taxes that are applied in a particular invoice and their amounts[in the tree view of a model account.invoice]
This is the output:

[image]

The column Tax Lines shows the ids of the taxes that are present in table account.invoice.tax (whereas I want to show their names and corresponding amount)

The model account.invoice has a field called tax_line_ids[Tax Lines] that contains the record of all the taxes on a invoice which is stored in a separate table account.invoice.tax, which in its own tree view looks like this:

[image]

I want to extract the tax name and its corresponding amount for it to reflect in account.invoice's tree view

Here's my python code which does'nt seem to work:

```
@api.one
def taxz(self):
    tax_pool = self.pool.get("account.tax")
    found_taxes = tax_pool.read(cr, uid, [tax_id,], ["tax_line_ids"], context)
    found_tax = found_taxes[0] if found_taxes else None
    tax_line_ids = found_tax["tax_line_ids"]
    _logger.critical("context type: " + type(context))
    _logger.critical("context content: " + str(context))
    _logger.critical(tax_line_ids)
```

xml code for the view:

```
<field name="tax_line_ids" widget="many2many_tags" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
    class Invoice(models.Model):
        _inherit = 'account.invoice'

        tax_line_ids = fields.Many2many('account.invoice.tax',
                                        'invoice_taxes', 
                                        'invoice_id', 
                                        'taxt_id',
                                        'List of taxes',
                                    compute='get_tax_list', store=True)



        @api.depends('tax_line', 'tax_line.amount')
        def get_tax_list(self):
            for rec in self:
                if rec.taxe_line:
                    rec.tax_line_ids = [(6,0,rec.tax_line.ids)]
                else:
                    rec.tax_line_ids = [(5,0,0)]
```

But doing this will just show the list of taxes without amount in your tree view
if you want to show the amount you need to override the `name_get` method in `account.invoice.tax`
but this will affect all the `x2many` fields.

```py
class AcountInvoiceTax(models.Model):

    _inherit = 'account.invoice.tax'

    @api.multi
    def name_get(self):
        res = []
        for rec in self:
            res.append((rec.id, rec.name +': '+ str(rec.amount)))
        return res
```

If you don't want this then you need to change the type to `Char` and recompute the field
or create another `model` to save taxes and define `name_get` for that model.

As you can see this worked for me now if you still getting the keyErro you must be doing some thing wrong check your code for indentation inherit value... :

[image]

Comment: Just tried the first part and it does'nt work [shows an empty list]
I changed the @api.depends to tax_line_ids as it was showing key error otherwise.

Comment: The problem that it should work try to put a print in the beginning of the method to see if it's called or not

Comment: sorry it was my mistake the name is tax_line not taxe_line

Comment: I changed that already and it still did'nt work. Plus the control does'nt go in the function , I put a _logger and it did'nt print anything.

Comment: where did you put the method that method belong to account.invoice and account.invoice have that field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159795/discussion-between-maharshirawal-and-tchi-odoo).

Comment: can you post your code the full class that you wrote

Answer (score 0):

You can do add a char field just to use it in display in treeview :

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
        _inherit = 'account.invoice'

        tax_line_tree_view = fields.Char(compute='get_tax_list')

        @api.multi
        def get_tax_list(self):
             tax_disp = ""
             for rec in self:
                  if rec.taxe_line:
                       for tax in taxe_line:
                            tax_disp = tax_disp + "["+tax.name+"], " 
                       rec.tax_line_tree_view = tax_disp[:-2] # [:-2] just to remove the last ', ' characters.
                  else:
                       rec.tax_line_tree_view  = tax_disp
```

In your XML file where tree_view is located, add this field:

```
<field name="tax_line_tree_view " />
```

instead of tax_line_ids.

I hope that answer your question.